# FactoryGirl : How to pass the attribute's value in factory to it's association

Tags: factory-bot

How can I pass the 'email' attribute value in a :subscriber factory to it's association :authentication

Eg :

```
factory :subscriber, :class => Subscriber do                                                                                                   
  sequence(:name) { |n| "test_user_#{n}" }                                                                                                     
  sequence(:email) { |n| "test_user_#{n}@example.com"}                                                                                                                   
  association :authentication, factory: :authentication, email: email       
end

factory :authentication do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "test_user_#{n}@example.com"} 
  password 'pass'
end
```

Is giving me error

```
ArgumentError:
   Trait not registered: email
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your association call dynamic because of the email variable that can change:

```
authentication {association :authentication, email: email}
```

Comment: Well.. this will trigger ```[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html```